# Identifying the tail recursion call of this function

Tags: c, recursion

So I have a function that searchs for a certain number in an unordered array. I know that the last line of the function is the tail recursion call because is the last line. I know that in a tail recursion call the returns of the functions that this recursive call will call, are the same so that operations are all done before the recursion call.

But my question is, how can I know that this recursion call of my function `ret = search_array (n , array , low , mid - 1)` is not a tail recursion call?

I see easily other examples of tail recursion like the factorial number with an accumulator as a parameter but in this case I can not identify the tail recursion as easy as in other functions.

```
int search_array (int n , int * array , int low , int high ) {
    int mid , ret ;

    if ( low > high ) {
        return -1;
    }

    mid = ( low + high ) / 2;
    if ( array [ mid ] == n ) {
        return mid ;
    }

    ret = search_array (n , array , low , mid - 1) ;
    if ( ret != -1) {
       return ret ;
    }

    return search_array (n , array , mid + 1 , high ) ;
}
```

Comment: would it be optimized with declared ints?

Comment: Well, it is not a tail recursion because the function is doing something with the result of this call *after* it was made (checks for `-1` and does some logic).

Comment: A tail recursion is the one, where it does not have to return to it's direct calling instance, but can return right to the top-level caller instead without affecting the result.

Comment: Disassemble it with a tool such as https://godbolt.org/, optimizations on. If you find `call search_array` anywhere, then you know for sure that the code is horrible and recursion should not have been used. As a rule of thumb, never use recursion for any purpose, some 99% of all uses of it in C are just massive code smell.

Answer (score 1):

You say that

> I know that in a tail recursion call [... the function's] operations are all done before the recursion call.

You apparently see that that is satisfied by

> ```
>     return search_array (n , array , mid + 1 , high ) ;
> ```

Clearly, however, it is *not* satisfied by

> ```
>     ret = search_array (n , array , low , mid - 1) ;
> ```

because the assignment to `ret` of the return value of the recursive call cannot be performed before the call is executed.  That call is not tail recursive because the function must perform other operations after it returns.  Even if the value returned were certain to be the recursive call's return value (which it is not), the central concept is not what the function returns, but rather whether it performs further operations between the recursive call and executing a return.